# Canvas HTML return dataURL using async function

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to generate an image using canvas like this..

```
myImage.addEventListener("load", async () => {

    assembledImage.src = await createImage(myImage);
    
    console.log(assembledImage.src)

});

async function createImage(myImage,) {

    console.log(canvas.toDataURL());

    // Some functions to create canvas
    return canvas.toDataURL();

}
```

The `todataURL` inside the async function show me the correct image, but the one in the addEventListener is `undefined`

How can I return the value to the caller?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/tibotovubi/1/edit?html,js,console — I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with `async/await`.

You should read the contents of src once that is loaded on the `assembledImage`. So try this:

```
myImage.addEventListener("load", async () => {
   assembledImage.src = await createImage(myImage);
   assembledImage.onload = () => console.log(assembledImage.src)
});
```

Comment: It's not that. [The `src` property has a value as soon as you assign it a value](https://jsbin.com/zoqohomahe/1/edit?js,console).